# Duplicate a tab in gnome-terminal

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

When working with gnome-terminal, I found that I often want to open a second copy of a tab: e.g. during a ssh session, I may need a second session at the same host and same remote path; or a second `mc` when two panels aren't enough. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't duplicate the entire state of a tab. It would involve somehow copying a whole process tree, which (if possible at all) is black magic (and wouldn't even work with network connections).

The reason is because a terminal program only knows what processes are running under it, but not their internals, and especially not the state of *remote* processes. You *could* make it start a `ssh user@host` with the same arguments as the currently running `ssh`, but you cannot force it to the same remote path.`*`

---

`*` I sometimes do this: (connection A) `pwd > ~/foo;` (connection B) `cd $(< ~/foo)`